# Unpack tar.gz folder to part of filename

Tags: tar, gzip

I have a file `dagens_130325.tar.gz` containing the folder `dagens`. In one folder I have hundreds of these daily info. I would like to unpack `dagens_130325.tar.gz/dagens` to `130325` with all the files inside. Then `130326` etc.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution I came up with in the end

```
#!/bin/bash
search_dir=/yourdir/with/tar.gz
for entry in "$search_dir"/*.tar.gz
do
  substring=$(basename "$entry")
  echo $substring
  sub2=${substring:7:6}
  tar -xvzf $substring
  rm -rf $sub2
  mv dagens $sub2
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the right stack where to ask this kind of question, however try with

```
tar -zxvf dagens_130325.tar.gz -C /tmp/130325 dagens
```

This way, the folder `dagens` for the archive `dagens_130325.tar.gz` is going to be extracted into `/tmp/130325`. However, note that the target folder must exist, otherwise the command will fail

So, supposedly you have 4 archives in the form `dagens_1.tar.gz`, `dagens_2.tar.gz`, `...`, you can write an `extract.sh` file containing

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..4}
do
   mkdir /tmp/$i
   FILE="dagens_$i.tar.gz"
   tar -zxvf $FILE -C /tmp/$i dagens
done
```

Having this file the `execute` permission, being in the same folder as your archives and executing it should produced the result you asked.

Comment: That's too much info since it only works for one file. Maybe it's not possible without some use of Bash?

Comment: Honestly, without using `for` cycle and thus the shell I don't know how to do for several files. And sorry, I did not understand your question immediately. Give me 5 minutes to review the `for` version and I will add to the answer

Answer (score 0):

use

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in dagens_*.tar.gz
do
    from=${file%_*} #removes chars after _
    to=${file#*_}   #removes chars before _
    to=${to%.t*}    #removes chars after .t (.tar.gz)
    tar -zxf $file --show-transformed --transform "s/$from/$to/"
done
```

Comment: i thought you wanted run file per file.
i'll update the code so you can run as a bat.